# How can you program a cronjob to run only ONCE after 12am and 12pm

Tags: algorithm, datetime, time, cron

I am given the following problem:

1. There are two shifts. One shift starts at 12am and the other at 12pm.
2. At the beginning of each shift, generate some tasks (details not important).

Ordinarily, this is a trivial problem that can be solved with crontab. However, my company is running on Heroku and the *Heroku Scheduler* has the following interesting properties:

1. It can only run **every 10 mins, hour or daily**,
2. You cannot time when the scheduler will actually start. If you scheduler is running every 10 mins, all you can expect is that it will run between 4:00am to 4:10am.
3. It is possible that the scheduler encounters some error and crash. When this happens, the scheduler will restart immediately. As an example, if the scheduler crashed at 4:00 while it was running, it might run again at 4:01.

Is it possible to implement a cronjob that:

1. **executes once only once after 12am and 12pm**
2. without needing a database to track its execution time?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of doing this would be to have some cron server (not on Heroku) which runs a script at 12am and 12pm.
The script invoked by the cron could use the [Heroku Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference) to spin up a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) in your Heroku app (using the [Dyno Create](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-create) endpoint).

This method satisfies your requirements of executing only once at 12am and at 12pm, WITHOUT using a DB to track execution times.

The drawback of this method is that it is not a "pure Heroku" solution, and requires you to maintain some "external" server to trigger your cron jobs.

If you don't like the ideas of maintaining your own cron server for that, you could use some cloud solution to schedule your script. For example, I would imagine you could do this for free using [AWS Lambda with Scheduled Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html).
In this case, you would schedule your lambda function to run each day at 12am and 12pm, and your lambda function would spin up your Heroku one off dyno.

Of course if you would be willing to add some form of DB to your Heroku app, you could easily create a "pure Heroku" solution.